# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

```
 @IBAction func CreateButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)

    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity =
        NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "EventData",
                                   in: managedContext)!


    let newEvent = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                 insertInto: managedContext)


    newEvent.setValue( Venuetextfield.text!, forKey: "eventVenue")
    newEvent.setValue(Titletextfield.text!, forKey: "eventTitle")
    newEvent.setValue(Descriptiontextfield.text!, forKey: "eventDescription")
    newEvent.setValue(Datetime, forKey: "eventDateTime")
    // sending data to coredata.
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

    let _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Hey guys how can i make entityForName not nil where NSManagedObject is also searching for entity name?

I have also create a NSMangedObject class containing all the entity attributes.

Do I need to link my Model.xcdatamodel id file to view controller class?

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this,

```
    let categoryMaster = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "entity Name", into: managedContext) as! CategoryMaster //Here CategoryMaster is entity class which is the sub class of NSManageObject

    categoryMaster.categoryId = NSNumber.init(value: 1)
    categoryMaster.categoryIndent = NSNumber.init(value: 2)
    categoryMaster.categoryName = textFields.text
    categoryMaster.parentCategory = currentCategory.categoryId
    categoryMaster.categoryIndex = NSNumber.init(value: 0)

    guard (try? managedContext.save()) != nil else
    {
            fatalError("Something went wrong")
    }
```

You can check out whole tutorial [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/173972/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial-2)

Note : This is just an example for how to use core data, you may find some syntax errors

Comment: Hey Hitesh thanks for replying BUT you havent declared "managedContext".So when i made changes in my code as you have suggested it is giving me error like "Use of unresolved identifier Managedobject"

Comment: Hi, I have not declared because you have already done that declaration in your question's code

Comment: yeah i  already guessed that part and edted it but now its giving error "use of undeclared type entity"

Comment: I think there is some problem in your implementation of core data entity so to verify everything please refer the tutorial link i have provided you so you will get the whole idea that how to implement core data